# Here's the problem with narrow 'column' layout of stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, mobile-web, usability

Stackexchange's 'column layout' leaves over 50% of my screen space unused. I can understand this is for design purposes, and in most cases it's not a problem.

However, especially on 'sub stacks' like stackoverflow where a lot of code fragments are used in posts, it becomes a problem.

Here's what I mean: [[Click here for full resolution screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3DoW.png)

[image]

Especially when reading through code that doesn't fit horizontally in the narrow single column layout that stackexchange imposes on us, this is extremely inconvenient.

Can this be made optional, so that users of non-mobile devices have the possibility to use all or at least more of their precious screen real estate?

Comment: Can you present this in a more professional manner?

Comment: [Wide Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange](https://georgegarside.com/blog/wide-stack-overflow-stack-exchange/) stylesheet

Comment: @jonsca This wasn't meant sarcastic or condescending, I just reckoned an image would say more than a long textual description of the issue. Do you consider it inept, or did I misexpress myself? (in that case, apologies, I'm not a native english speaker)

Comment: @grgarside Thanks, that seems interesting! However I have no idea how or where to use or apply that? I noticed you're referring to Stylish for Safari, would you happen to know a way of using this in Firefox?

Comment: @RocketNuts I wouldn't use the word *suck* in the title if it isn't clear that you are using it as joke.

Comment: @RocketNuts There's a [Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/stylish/) but I don't use Firefox myself to try it.

Comment: @RocketNuts I was referring to the point that rene already made.  A designer has worked very hard on the design, and it was mildly insulting to insinuate that it "sucked," Presenting it as a mild flaw to be addressed would have been much better received.

Answer (score 2):

The UI is based on the screen a majority of the SE users is using, and that isn't a screen that is common to some users (on 4K screens for example). The UI will show fine on a width of 1024, and the white space is gone then.

I like the spacious design of the question page, and I don't think we should change it now. Maybe in the future, when high-resolution screens are more common, an adjustment can be made.

Comment: While I understand this is not something that can be simply switched or enabled at the press of a button, the first question that comes to mind is: why basing a UI on any specific screen size at all? There are many tools and methods (also non-complicated ones) to make a website work fine on (and make proper use of) pretty much any resolution.

Comment: I guess the remaining argument is: because [Jin](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) liked it.